# what is the value of $a and $b after the function call and why? (pass by reference and pass by value)

Tags: php

what is the value of $a and $b after the function call and why?

Just to clarify the difference between `pass by reference` and `pass by value`

> ```
> function doSomething( &$arg ) {
>     $return = $arg;
>     $arg += 1;
>     return $return; }
>
> $a = 3;
> $b = doSomething( $a );
> ```

Comment: what the use of & in &$arg?

Comment: @mornenel there are many places you can post for fun/entertainment and there's nothing wrong with that when done at the right site. This isn't that site though.

Comment: @JohnRobertson - it indicates "pass by reference" rather than simply "pass by value"

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for the reply but still I don't understand.

Comment: @JohnRobertson - "pass by value"... if you change the value of the argument within your function, it has no affect on the variable within the calling function; "pass by reference"... if you change the value of the argument within your function, it changes it in the calling function as well... example sort()

Comment: Now there's the light. Thank you very much @MarkBaker

Comment: @MarkBaker the calling function is $b = doSomething( $a ); right?

Comment: The calling function is the line `$b = doSomething( $a );` in the main body of the script; and because $a is being passed "by reference" the change to that argument within the function will also change it in the main body of the script as well - See the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a is 4

$b is 3

The former (`$a`) because `$arg` is passed by reference, the latter (`$b`) because the return value of the function is a copy of (not a reference to) the initial value of the argument.